# minSdk version in manifest prevents gradle sync with Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

> The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest
>   file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig
>   in the build.gradle file.

If you have the minSdk version specified in the manifest, starting with Android Studio 3.2 the build fails. Is there a way to ignore this warning and build successfully despite this warning?

Comment: Why not put it in the build.gradle, where it's supposed to be?

Comment: there will not be the problem if you will move minSDK version from manifest to build.gradle

Comment: There is if you still want the option of using other build systems.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with an app that builds with Android Make as well as Gradle. Removing the minSdk from the manifest file in that case is not possible because Android Make will default to API level 1.

Here's a bit of a hack to work around that issue.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile getModifiedManifestFile()

...

def getModifiedManifestFile() {
    File originalManifest = file(new File("./", "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"))
    String newFileContents = originalManifest.getText('UTF-8').replace("<uses-sdk\n" +
        "        android:minSdkVersion=\"26\"\n" +
        "        android:targetSdkVersion=\"28\" />", "")
    File tmpManifest = file(new File("./", "src/main/TempAndroidManifest.xml"))
    tmpManifest.write(newFileContents)
    tmpManifest.deleteOnExit()
    return tmpManifest
}
```

Just replace the regex so that it matches your file and the sync should pass. Also add the temporary file to the .gitignore file.

**Edit**: The original solution created the file in the OS temp folder, but Android Studio's Run configurations do not accept that - the file needs to be located in the project directory.

Comment: I'm new to Gradle. I made Unity create a Gradle template for me but I do not know how to merge this solution into my template file. Any chance you can help me with that @fejd?

Comment: @m4rkk Sorry, I'm not familiar with Unity template files but does it produce a build.gradle file? Is that a one time operation or does Unity keep the build.gradle file in sync with the template? If it just happens once, and Unity doesn't overwrite the file, then maybe you can manually edit the build.gradle file to include this workaround?